# How to create a url pattern for a specific node

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I have a node with the path: http://www.example.com/test

I would like all paths that begin with /test/ to go to this node. url like these:
http://www.example.com/test/a/b/c
http://www.example.com/test/a?bc

all should be redirected to this node.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Not with Drupal (that I am aware of). You will need to add a redirect to your .htaccess file. There is a lot of info on the net about how to do this, but this looks like a good place to start: [How can I use htaccess to redirect paths with a wildcard character](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6877581/4483099)

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, you can use `Pathauto` module. To set a specific path for a specific node, go to admin/modules/pathauto/config and set the path for that specific node in the textbox as you want. For your case use `test/[node:title]` in the Pattern for all test paths text field.

Comment: Although it sounds a bit like the OP is asking about setting up URL patterns, I'm pretty sure he/she is actually asking *how to redirect to a node based on a URL pattern*.